# AirConsole Send-Message limit

Tags: airconsole

According to the help page:

> You can not send more than 10 messages per second. However, all messages will be queued, so that no message will be lost.

But what does this mean?  Can each device send 10 messages, or can only 10 messages be sent for the game altogether?  If the latter, 10 messages per second would seem like a crippling limit for a game if 10 people were playing and each controller needs to send what buttons are being pressed and released, how can that be dealt with?  And how do changes to device states affect the message count?

On a somewhat related note, why does the page mention latencies of different servers if the connection seems to be established over local wifi?  (I assume the answer bears some relation to why there's a message limit at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Rate limiting is per device. Each device can send up to 10 messages per second.

Custom Device State updates also count towards this rate limit.

We've created a library that intelligently rate-limits your messages and updates: [RateLimiter](https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-controls/tree/master/rate-limiter)

The connections are not established over local Wifi. WebRTC is supported, but that might not be in the same Wifi network. Additionally not all browsers support WebRTC yet (e.g. Safari iOS). [More details in this presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1t40cmrv7NT45rRwsJUXqZC2uOmZBS0Cbs9jG1J_Jdzc/edit).